# How to make Foreground Service notification non-dismissible in Android OS 14

Tags: android

We can use Notification.Builder.setOngoing(true) to make the notification non-dismissible in Android OS 13.

However, Android 14 has changed the behavior to allow users to dismiss such notifications.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications

Is there any other way to make Foreground Service notification non-dismissible in Android OS 14 ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to listen to the broadcast when the notification is dismissed and show the notification again.

- When creating the notification, set the `PendingIntent` which is fired when the notification is dismissed by the user using the `setDeleteIntent(PendingIntent)`:

```
fun showNotification() {
    val dismissedIntent = Intent("DISMISSED_ACTION")
    dismissedIntent.setPackage(packageName) // This is required on Android 14
    val dismissedPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        requestCode,
        dismissedIntent,
        flags
    )

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("your title")
        .setContentText("your content")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tracking_notification_animation)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setDeleteIntent(dismissedPendingIntent)
        ....
        .build()

    startForeground(YOUR_ID, notification)
}
```

- Create a `BroadcastReceiver` which shows the notification again when it is dismissed:

```
private val onNotificationDismissedReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        showNotification()
    }
}
```

- Register the receiver:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    ...
    registerReceiver(
        onNotificationDismissedReceiver,
        IntentFilter("DISMISSED_ACTION"),
        RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED // This is required on Android 14
    )
    ...
}
```

- Don't forget to unregister the receiver:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    ...
    unregisterReceiver(onNotificationDismissedReceiver)
    ...
}
```

Comment: solution to make your app suspended? let's not do hacks

Answer (score -1):

Use following files for non stop background service

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import java.util.Timer;

import coding.work.station.gpos.R;


public class NotificationService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationService";
    private Timer timer;
    private Handler mHandler;


    Runnable minuteService = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


            } finally {
                mHandler.postDelayed(minuteService, 60 * 1000);
            }
        }
    };


    Runnable hoursService = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

            } finally {
                mHandler.postDelayed(hoursService, 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //this is commnet becouse i am testing in emnulater @Navin
            startMyOwnForeground();
        } else {
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
        }

    }

    private void startMyOwnForeground() {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "coding.work.station";
        String channelName = "My Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        Handler handler2 = new Handler();
        handler2.postDelayed(() -> {
            mHandler = new Handler();
            startRepeatingTask();
        }, 5000);   //5 seconds

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stoptimertask();
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("RestartService");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, RestartService.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }


    public void stoptimertask() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    void startRepeatingTask() {
        mStatusChecker.run();
    }

    Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


            } finally {
                mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, 1000);
            }
        }
    };


}


RestartService.java

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class RestartService extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            //context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
        }
    }
}


// add this in menifest
<service
            android:name=".backGroundService.NotificationService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".backGroundService.RestartService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


// Add this in your main activity

mYourService = new NotificationService();
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, mYourService.getClass());

        if (!isMyServiceRunning(mYourService.getClass())) {
            startService(mServiceIntent);
        }


 private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                //Log.i("Service status", "Running");
                return true;
            }
        }
        //Log.i("Service status", "Not running");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! 2 concerns. 1. after OS 12, starting Foreground Service is limited to several exemptions. Otherwise we will get an exception. 2. dismissing the notification does not stop the Foreground service. I am looking for a solution to non-dismissible notification, not to restart the service.